# Limit of a sequence indexed by reals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

A sequence is generally indexed by the positive integers, how come we dont have to use nets when we consider say the continuity of a function, in other words when we take the limit in an uncoutable index set?

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: @Michael Klyachman better?

Comment: We don't take a "limit of an uncountable index set". For continuity of a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ we require, that for all sequences (with countable index set) $(x_n)$ with common limit $x$, the limit of the sequence $(f(x_n))$ is equal to $f(x)$.

Comment: Sequentially continuous implies continuous in a first countable topological space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason has to do with the topology of $\mathbb R$. Convergence in the reals with the usual topology is fully captured sequentially. Nets are required when when we are in a topological space where convergence by means of open sets is not equivalent to sequential convergence. It is a property of the reals as a topological space that sequentiality is enough. For instance, you are probably familiar with the fact that a metric space is compact iff it is sequentially compact. Limits of functions are not uncountable versions of limits of sequences. Sequences as a tool in the study of functions works in the reals because of their topology.

Comment: Good answer, not so easy to know when one is introduced to this first year at university!

Comment: Just to clarify, when we write $\lim$ in general this means an uncoutable sequence? While in the reals this is equivallent to for any countble sequence?

Comment: is that correct?